# How do I capture specific words in a string?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I want to capture only the names of the various departments and the numbers of students in:

```
line = "The Biology department averages 32 students/class"
```

I've tried `re.search(r"\s\D+\d", line)` but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 2):

A bit more explicit approach than Christian's answer, using [lookahead](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#regular-expression-syntax):

```
>>> s = "The Biology department averages 32 students/class"
>>> dept = r'\s+(\w+)\s+(?=department)'
>>> students = r'\s+(\d+)\s+(?=students)'
>>> re.findall(dept, s),re.findall(students,s)
(['Biology'], ['32'])
```

Answer (score 1):

```
In [3]: department, students = re.search(r"(?:The\s+)?([A-Z]\w*).*\s+(\d+)\s+", line).groups()

In [4]: print department, students
Biology 32
```

Comment: How can I combine all that into one line?

Comment: @user3852341, I've updated the answer. Is that what you wanted?

Answer (score 1):

A bit more clearer method,LOL

```
# encoding: UTF-8
import re
s = 'The Biology department averages 32 students/class'
pattern1 = re.compile(r'.*?The (.*?) department')
match1 = pattern1.match(s)
if match1:
    print match1.group(1)
pattern2 = re.compile(r'.*? (\d.?) students')
match2 = pattern2.match(s)
if match2:
    print match2.group(1)
```